# Custom exceptions - Am I doing it right?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently writing a .net REST web api, and am using custom exceptions so that I can send back detailed information to the client as well as the correct http response to stay compliant with REST.. but it seems like I am explicitly throwing a lot of exceptions.

For example: I have an API for uploading image files. These image files have to be a certain file format and under a certain size. If my code finds that an image is the wrong file format, I throw a new custom exception like:

`throw new FileTypeException();`

Or, if the file is too big, meaning the file.Size() is greater than an amount I have set in the web.config, I throw a different custom exception like:

```
throw new FileSizeException();
```

I then catch these exceptions in my Post() method and return a 400 BadRequest and a reason.

So, my code is not actually throwing an error, its just the request does not meet specifications. Is this bad practice?

Comment: this seems like a rather opinion based question to me. I am creating new `Exception`s if (and only if) the `catch`-implementation differs from other exceptions. generally: as many as necessary, but as few as possible

Comment: IMHO, the exceptions should be catch in a filter instead of catching in each method.

Answer (score 1):

This might be more appropriate as a Programming question rather than Stack Overflow.

Throwing custom exceptions can be very useful in the right scenario, and a lot of unnecessary work and complexity in the wrong scenario.  Usually the sanity check I use, is different handling for each distinct exception type.

For example, your FileTypeException and FileSizeException - is there a different `catch` for each type?  Or are you just returning a different message?

If it's the latter, try to consolidate where you can or use the framework provided exceptions.  If it's the former, then you're using custom exceptions right.

Answer (score 0):

An exception filter works great for these cases. In your WebApiConfig, register an exception filter

```
config.Filters.Add(new CustomExceptionFilterAttribute());
```

Code for a basic filter:

```
//needed for CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, message)
using System.Net.Http

public class CustomExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        //you can get the underlying exception here
        var type = context.Exception.GetType();

        //I like to map exception types to status codes
        var statusCode = GetHttpStatusCode(type);

        //respond with a proper status code and the message
        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(statusCode, context.Exception.Message);
    }
}
```

Now in any controller code you can throw and it will hit your filter

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    throw new FileSizeException();
}
```